# R download.file, downloading excel file does not work

Tags: r, excel

I try to download an excel file using download.file().

If I go directly to the link using the browser, I can download the file without problems.

However, using download.file does only download a broken file with Excel error: "The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension."

Here is my code:

```
url <- "http://obieebr.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Download&Format=excel2007&Extension=.xlsx&BypassCache=true&path=%2Fshared%2fSeries%20Estad%c3%adsticas%2F1.%20Tasa%20Interbancaria%20%28TIB%29%2F1.1.TIB_Serie%20hist%C3%B3rica%20IQY&lang=es&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico&SyncOperation=1"
download.file(url, destfile = paste0(base_dir, "test.xls"), mode = "wb", method="libcurl")
```

Any ideas how to download this file?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: In the `url` object there  is `Extension=.xlsx` and the `destfile` is a `.xls`. Possibly something to check.

Comment: @tictochoc Thank you for your reply, yes, that is an error, the `destfile` should be `test.xlsx`. However, it still does not work to download that file properly.

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: @LuckySeedling It downloads the file but the error is the same if I open it in Excel: "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it works for me:

```
download.file(url,destfile = "./second.xlsx",mode = "wb")
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how is your call different from what OP already tried? I know, you omit `method` param and used a possible different `destfile`, but why this should work and OPs call not?

Comment: @Paul Roub, thank you for your solution. I tried it but on my computer, the excel file is still corrupted, did it work on your side to open the excel file?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the answer for readability. @abhsihek would need to explain or discuss it.

Comment: To figure out what's going on, it would be useful to know the OS on which this solution works.

Comment: wb means "write binary", which treats the output as non-text (binary) or a string of bytes. That way, no fussing is done with the underlying excel workbook data.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to download is simply not an excel file. Actually what you obtain is an html file (try to change the file extension to '.html', then open in your browser). So your code is not the problem.